# Sample rate synchronization

Tags: software-implementation

I'm currently working on a digital audio OFDM project and found that even if I explicitly specified the same sample rate (11025 Hz), the transmitter and receiver still differ slightly in it(lesser than 1 Hz). My professor asked me to use a 'multirate interpolating filter' to synchronize the two sample rates. Could you give me some hints about it?

By the way, I'm programming with C++ and the portaudio library. Thanks.